# Make method more Rx like by replacing List<T> and TaskCompletionSource<T>

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

This is a request-response model (like HTTP) but over sockets/websockets. We know which response corresponds to which request by comparing the request IDs.

The workflow is as following:

1. Subscribe to the observables `Error`, `ContractDetails` (`_itemObservable`) and `ContractDetailsEnd` (`_itemEndObservable`)
2. Match request id to response id and push the corresponding messages via `.OnNext(...)` to `ContractDetails`. When there is nothing else left to push, push a final message to `ContractDetailsEnd` which essentially does `.OnCompleted`.
3. Cleanup – unsubscribe, i.e. dispose the observables

---

In the first snippet below I use a `List<TItemArgs>`, `CancellationTokenSource` and a `TaskCompletionSource<TItemArgs>`. That's completely unnecessary if everything was Rx style. It would have definitely been less lines of code too.

The second snippet is my personal attempt to make it look more Rx like. It has some issues that I want to resolve:

- I don't think the try/catch block is necessary since `.Subscribe` could handle errors
- `.Timeout` didn't work out for me – if the request is not matched within a few seconds, it should return a `Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromError(new TimeoutError(...))`
- In addition to the errors, a message pushed to `_errorSubject` should also return an error such as `Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromError(new RemoteError(...))` but `.Merge(errorMessages.Any(_ => false))` is not working.

In my attempt I use `ReplaySubject` in opposed to `AsyncSubject` because I believe AsyncSubject is only useful when I'm only interested in the last value of the sequence and want to avoid getting all previous values, which is not in my case. In my case I want to return all values, so ReplaySubject would be more suitable as it keeps track of all the previous values and wants all subscribers to receive the same values, regardless of when they subscribed.

```cs
public async ValueTask<Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>> ExecuteAsync(Action<int> action)
{
    var requestId = _client.GetNextRequestId();

    var data = new List<TItemArgs>();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(_timeout);
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>();

    cts.Token.Register(() =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    }, false);

    void OnError(ErrorData msg)
    {
        tcs.SetException(new IBClientException(msg.RequestId, msg.Code, msg.Message, msg.AdvancedOrderRejectJson));
    }

    void OnDetails(TItemArgs item)
    {
        data.Add(item);
    }

    void OnDetailsEnd(TItemListEndArgs item)
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(data);
    }

    var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    
    _client.Error
        .Where(e => HasRequestId && e.RequestId == requestId)
        .Subscribe(OnError)
        .DisposeWith(disposable);

    _itemObservable
        .Where(item => MatchRequest(item, _itemRequestIdExtractor, requestId))
        .Subscribe(OnDetails)
        .DisposeWith(disposable);

    _itemEndObservable
        .Where(item => MatchRequest(item, _itemListEndRequestIdExtractor, requestId))
        .Subscribe(OnDetailsEnd)
        .DisposeWith(disposable);

    action(requestId);

    try
    {
        await tcs.Task.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
            cts.Dispose();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        
        return Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromSuccess(tcs.Task.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromError(new RemoteError(e.Message, null));
    }
}
```

### My attempt

```cs
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

var client = new IBClient();

var result = await client.GetContractDetailsAsync();

if (result.Success)
{
    foreach (var item in result.Data!)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RequestId: {item.RequestId} | Data: {item.ContractDetails}");
    }
}

public sealed class IBClient
{
    private int _nextValidId;
    
    private readonly Subject<ErrorData> _errorSubject = new();
    public IObservable<ErrorData> Error => _errorSubject.AsObservable();
    
    private readonly Subject<ContractDetailsData> _contractDetailsSubject = new();
    public IObservable<ContractDetailsData> ContractDetails => _contractDetailsSubject.AsObservable();

    private readonly Subject<RequestEndData> _contractDetailsEndSubject = new();
    public IObservable<RequestEndData> ContractDetailsEnd => _contractDetailsEndSubject.AsObservable();
    
    public ValueTask<Result<IEnumerable<ContractDetailsData>>> GetContractDetailsAsync()
    {
        return new PendingRequest<ContractDetailsData, RequestEndData>(
                this,
                ContractDetails,
                ContractDetailsEnd,
                e => e.RequestId,
                e => e.RequestId)
            .ExecuteAsync(reqId => TestCall(reqId));
    }

    private void TestCall(int requestId)
    {
        _contractDetailsSubject.OnNext(new ContractDetailsData(requestId, "hey from test call"));
        _contractDetailsSubject.OnNext(new ContractDetailsData(requestId, "hey two"));

        // TODO: Errors doesn't seem to work
        // _errorSubject.OnNext(new ErrorData(requestId, 123, "Error happened", ""));

        _contractDetailsEndSubject.OnNext(new RequestEndData(requestId));

        // There shouldn't be matched.
        _contractDetailsSubject.OnNext(new ContractDetailsData(123, "fake ones, so we know it works"));
        _contractDetailsEndSubject.OnNext(new RequestEndData(123));
    }
    
    public int GetNextRequestId()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _nextValidId);
    }
}

public sealed class PendingRequest<TItemArgs, TItemListEndArgs>
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    private readonly IBClient _client;

    private readonly IObservable<TItemArgs> _itemObservable;
    private readonly IObservable<TItemListEndArgs> _itemEndObservable;
    private readonly Func<TItemArgs, int>? _itemRequestIdExtractor;
    private readonly Func<TItemListEndArgs, int>? _itemListEndRequestIdExtractor;

    public PendingRequest(
        IBClient client,
        IObservable<TItemArgs> itemObservable,
        IObservable<TItemListEndArgs> itemEndObservable,
        Func<TItemArgs, int>? itemRequestIdExtractor = null,
        Func<TItemListEndArgs, int>? itemListEndRequestIdExtractor = null)
    {
        _client = client;

        _itemObservable = itemObservable;
        _itemEndObservable = itemEndObservable;

        _itemRequestIdExtractor = itemRequestIdExtractor;
        _itemListEndRequestIdExtractor = itemListEndRequestIdExtractor;
    }

    private bool HasRequestId => _itemRequestIdExtractor != null && _itemListEndRequestIdExtractor != null;

    public async ValueTask<Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>> ExecuteAsync(Action<int> action, IScheduler? scheduler = null)
    {
        scheduler ??= ImmediateScheduler.Instance;

        var requestId = _client.GetNextRequestId();
        var results = new ReplaySubject<TItemArgs>();

        try
        {
            var errorMessages = _client.Error
                .Where(e => HasRequestId && e.RequestId == requestId);

            using (_itemObservable
                       .Where(item => MatchRequest(item, _itemRequestIdExtractor, requestId))
                       .ObserveOn(scheduler)
                       .Subscribe(results))
            using (_itemEndObservable
                       .Any(item => MatchRequest(item, _itemListEndRequestIdExtractor, requestId))
                       .Merge(errorMessages.Any(_ => false)) // TODO: ???
                       .ObserveOn(scheduler)
                       .Subscribe(_ => results.OnCompleted()))
            {
                action(requestId);

                // Don't want an Exception thrown if there result list is empty
                await results.DefaultIfEmpty();

                return Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromSuccess(results.ToEnumerable());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromError(new RemoteError(ex.Message, null));
        }
    }
    
    private bool MatchRequest<T>(T item, Func<T, int>? idExtractor, int id)
    {
        return !HasRequestId || (idExtractor != null && idExtractor(item) == id);
    }
}

public sealed class ContractDetailsData
{
    public ContractDetailsData(int requestId, string contractDetails)
    {
        RequestId = requestId;
        ContractDetails = contractDetails;
    }

    public int RequestId { get; }

    public string ContractDetails { get; }
}

public sealed class ErrorData
{
    public ErrorData(int requestId, int code, string message, string advancedOrderRejectJson)
    {
        RequestId = requestId;
        Code = code;
        Message = message;
        AdvancedOrderRejectJson = advancedOrderRejectJson;
    }

    public int RequestId { get; }
    public int Code { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
    public string AdvancedOrderRejectJson { get; }
}

public sealed class RequestEndData
{
    public RequestEndData(int requestId)
    {
        RequestId = requestId;
    }

    public int RequestId { get; }
}

public class IBClientException : Exception
{
    public IBClientException(int requestId, int errorCode, string message, string advancedOrderRejectJson)
        : base(message)
    {
        RequestId = requestId;
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
        AdvancedOrderRejectJson = advancedOrderRejectJson;
    }

    public IBClientException(string err)
        : base(err)
    {
    }

    public IBClientException(Exception e)
    {
        Exception = e;
    }

    public int RequestId { get; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; }
    public string? AdvancedOrderRejectJson { get; }
    public Exception? Exception { get; }
}

public abstract record Error(int? Code, string Message, object? Data);

public record RemoteError : Error
{
    public RemoteError(string message, object? data) : base(null, message, data)
    {
    }

    public RemoteError(int? code, string message, object? data) : base(code, message, data)
    {
    }
}

public record Result<T>(bool Success, T? Data, Error? Error)
{
    public Result(T data) : this(true, data, default)
    {
    }

    public Result(Error error) : this(false, default, error)
    {
    }

    public static Result<T> FromSuccess(T data)
    {
        return new Result<T>(data);
    }

    public static Result<T> FromError<TError>(TError error) where TError : Error
    {
        return new Result<T>(error);
    }
}

public static class DisposableExtensions
{
    public static T DisposeWith<T>(this T disposable, ICollection<IDisposable> collection)
        where T : IDisposable
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(disposable);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(collection);

        collection.Add(disposable);
        return disposable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could post `IBClient` and `ErrorData` - and any dependencies?

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry, I was being tired yesterday. There is no issue with the messages themselves. Technically the messages should be pushed via `.OnNext` until `_itemEndObservable`/`RequestEndData` message is received. You can take a look at the `TestCall` method. The issue is only with the errors. You can uncomment `_errorSubject.OnNext`. In case of an error, it should return `Result<IEnumerable<TItemArgs>>.FromError(new RemoteError(ex.Message, null))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I've cleaned up the question and comments as I think it expresses what I need in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good start:

```
    IObservable<TItemArgs> observable =
        Observable
            .Merge(
                _itemObservable
                   .Where(item => MatchRequest(item, _itemRequestIdExtractor, requestId))
                   .Select(item => Notification.CreateOnNext(item))
                   .Take(1),
               _itemEndObservable
                   .Any(item => MatchRequest(item, _itemListEndRequestIdExtractor, requestId))
                   .Select(item => Notification.CreateOnCompleted<TItemArgs>()))
           .Dematerialize();
```

---

And here's a final observable without the `ReplaySubject`.

```
private static async Task<Result<IEnumerable<Details>>> Test(IScheduler scheduler) =>
    await
        Observable
            .Defer(() =>
            {
                var client = new IBClient();
                var requestId = 1;
                return Observable.Create<Result<IEnumerable<Details>>>(o =>
                {
                    IDisposable subscription =
                        Observable
                            .Merge(
                                client.Details.Where(x => x.RequestId == requestId).Select(x => Notification.CreateOnNext(x)),
                                client.DetailsEnd.Any(x => x.RequestId == requestId).Select(x => Notification.CreateOnCompleted<Details>()),
                                client.Error.Where(x => x.RequestId == requestId).Select(x => Notification.CreateOnError<Details>(new Exception($"Code: {x.Code}, Message: {x.Message}"))))
                            .Dematerialize()
                            .Synchronize()
                            .ToArray()
                            .Select(items => Result<IEnumerable<Details>>.FromSuccess(items))
                            .Catch<Result<IEnumerable<Details>>, Exception>(ex => Observable.Return(Result<IEnumerable<Details>>.FromError(new Error(null, ex.Message, null))))
                        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                        .ObserveOn(scheduler)
                        .Subscribe(o);

                    client.Emit(2, 4);
                    client.Emit(requestId, 42);
                    client.EmitEnd(2);
                    client.Emit(requestId, 62);
                    client.Emit(requestId, 123);
                    //client.EmitError(requestId, 123, "Something bad happened");
                    client.EmitEnd(requestId);
                    client.Emit(requestId, 1);

                    return subscription;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I also did https://pastebin.com/u6AF6YtS but I was unable to make the errors work at all. I like your example but I think there shouldn't be `.Take(1)` as there are multiple elements before `_itemEndObservable` calls OnCompleted. How do I return `IEnumerable<TItemArgs>` out of it?

Comment: @nop - with the `await observable` call you discard all but the last value from an observable. So that's why I put in the `.Take(1)`. Otherwise you need to put in a `.ToArray()` at the end of the `.Dematerialize()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it never passed through `await observables` https://i.imgur.com/gPdPAZ5.png

Comment: @nop - Then your observables didn't fire or didn't complete.

Comment: @nop - try this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WOH2YV

Comment: Oh I see, the difference is that in my example I actually have a `ReplaySubject` and in opposed of `Notification.CreateOnNext(item)`, I'm actually adding the elements to that `ReplaySubject`. https://pastebin.com/u6AF6YtS. In your example, it displays only the last one `subjectValue.OnNext(42); subjectValue.OnNext(62); subjectValue.OnNext(123); subjectCompleted.OnNext(Unit.Default); subjectValue.OnNext(1);` - in this example it should display 42, 62, 123.

Comment: Nvm, it's because I never subscribe to `_itemObservable` and `_itemEndObservable`. But what should I do in the .Subscribe in your case?

Comment: Here is fiddle where I'm getting the expected results but the `timeout` and `errorSignal` are broken. https://dotnetfiddle.net/vCTQqw

Comment: @nop - Here's a version of my code that receives multiple values: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WOH2YV.

Comment: @nop - Here's a version of your code that works with my style observable: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eN67w0

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code looks so clean and suit! Probably a last question: https://pastebin.com/aQATTJLa - does everything look good? I added timeout and it seems to be working when I put the timeout to 0 seconds. Not sure if `ObserveOn` is appropriate in this use case

Comment: @nop - Your code looks good now. The use of `ObserveOn` might cause a timeout of `0` to fail, but I see your code has it set to `2` seconds. That should be fine. Also, try to get you error handling inside the observable rather than throwing around `try`/`catch` blocks.

Comment: but how do I return `return Result<IEnumerable<Details>>.FromError(new Error(null, ex.Message, null))` there if it fails

Comment: @nop - here's how: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Babkij. The code is a lot neater with the last line being `return await results;`.